# How to obtain 3D symmetrical points with reference to a plane - Python (NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, point-clouds

I have a point cloud with several points that should be symmetrical. So I have 2 question:

1. How can I divide the point cloud (given with cartesian coordinates - x,y,z) by the symmetrical plane (ax+by+cz+d=0) ?
2. If I have points defined by the arrays x, y and z and the plane ax+by+cz+d=0, how can I get the symmetrical arrays (x',y' and z') to the plane?

Already have the 2nd question solved. Anyone knows how to locate a point relative to a plane?

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742653/symmetrical-point-with-respect-to-a-plane) of interest?

Comment: @Ivan kinda yes. I'm just having troubles implementing it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show any progress made with the implementation of the method.

Comment: @Ivan I'm at the first question. Trying to figure out how to divide the point cloud by the plane

Comment: What do you mean by *divide*?

Comment: For example, I have point cloud from a tree and I want to cut it in half, like creating an array for lhe left side and an array to the right side

Answer (score 1):

Having arbitrary point `O` lying in the plane (r [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755856/calculate-arbitrary-points-from-a-plane-equation)) and normalized normal `n`, one can find orthogonal projection of point `P` onto the plane

```
R = P - dot(P - O, n) * n
```

To get point symmetrical against the plane

```
P' = P + 2*(R-P) = 2 * R - P
```

Simple implementation (numpy undoubtly has some functions for vector calculation)

```
import math
def mirror(px, py, pz, a, b, c, d):
    squaredsum = a*a+b*b+c*c
    normlen = 1.0 / math.sqrt(squaredsum)
    nx = a * normlen
    ny = b * normlen
    nz = c * normlen
    ox = a * d / squaredsum
    oy = b * d / squaredsum
    oz = c * d / squaredsum
    dott = nx * (px - ox) + ny * (py - oy) + nz * (pz - oz)
    rx = px - nx * dott
    ry = py - ny * dott
    rz = pz - nz * dott
    symx = 2 * rx - px
    symy = 2 * ry - py
    symz = 2 * rz - pz
    return (symx, symy, symz)

print(mirror(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3))
>>>(2.0000000000000004, 2.0000000000000004, 2.0000000000000004)
```

Comment: px, py and pz can be the arrays with the coordinates right?

Comment: do u have ay ideia how to divide the point cloud by this plane. Like define a left and a right side of the cloud?

Comment: You can calculate [moments of point cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) - 2nd moments to find axis (axes) - it should correspond to the normal of plane of symmetry, 1st moment defines mass center - point in the plane

Comment: this function just works for 1 point. to run the complete array at the same time I have to encounter the correspondent numpy functions?

Comment: I think yes (not familiar with numpy). But precalculate n normal and o point as common parameters